# Excel | Largest Number in Array with Condition

Tags: excel, array-formulas

I am trying to find the largest inventory total with a specific date.

In Excel, I'm using the function 
`{(LARGE(IF(A:A=V2),K:K),1)}` where `A:A`is a list of dates, `V2` is a specific date, and `K:K` are inventory totals. The function returns "0". When I adjust for the 2nd largest or 3rd largest I receive a `#NUM` error.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: without seeing the data and the formulas you tried for the 2nd and 3rd, it is hard to speculate.  Did you remember to use Ctrl-Shift-Enter?  Are there more than 1 values for that date?  Are you still referring to `V2` in the other formulas?  Are the values in Column A true dates or strings that look like dates?  Is the value in V2 a true date or a string that looks like a date?  Do they match?  Too Many Questions, not enough data.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up, Scott.

2nd = {(LARGE(IF(A:A=V2),K:K),2)}
3rd = {(LARGE(IF(A:A=V2),K:K),3)}

There are more than 1 unique values for the same date. 

Column A are Formatted Dates {=DATE(YEAR(B134),MONTH(B134),DAY(1))}

I would like the ability to change V2 month over month but for this example let's say it 9/1/2017.

Answer (score 1):

I see you have some brackets wrongly put. try this formula. Enter it as an array formula.

```
=(LARGE(IF((A:A=V2),K:K),1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking a look Kresimir. I'm still getting a "0" value. Here's additional info: Column A are Formatted Dates {=DATE(YEAR(B134),MONTH(B134),DAY(1))} I would like the ability to change V2 month over month but for this example let's say it 9/1/2017.

Comment: Formula will work properly regardless of column A being formulae instead of values. if you are still getting an error, first check if value in cell V2 is really a date, and not a text value. not sure what you mean with "ability to change V2 months over month"...?